# cat shows file contents, gedit and vim show blank file

Tags: files, vim, cat, gedit

I was planning on building a current logging device with an Arduino, and tried starting off with the basic SD-card write example from the Arduino IDE sketchbook.

The Serial console showed no errors, so I assumed everything worked perfectly.

However... when I inserted the card in my computer (Ubuntu 18.04) and opened it with gedit, the file was blank? Vim had the same behaviour: it was blank.

But... when I used *cat* on the file, it DID show the contents?!

Anyone have a clue what I did wrong here?

EDIT: in reponse to Bodo's question:

output of cat:

```
...
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
372,345,324
342,340,330
331,332,328
327,325,324
322,320,318
317,315,313
313,310,309
...
```

(This is what's supposed to be in there)

out put of ls -l:

```
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 myname myname 15161 Jan  1  2000 DATALOG.TXT
```

output of od -c -tx1 DATALOG.TXT | head -1 :

```
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n
```

This last one answerd the question to me... It shows a bunch of newlines. But really... A LOT... This explains why gedit and vim showed empty files. I have to scroll down for ages before seeing the actual data. When using cat, I only saw the trailing lines, so it showed the contents. 
Probably something that went wrong when saving the data to the SD-card. Thanks Bodo! You solved my problem merely by posing a question :D

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l /location/of/your/sdcard`. What does `cat yourfile` show? Or `od -c -tx1 yourfile | head -10`?

Comment: @Bodo: I added the outputs to the question. But... by executing those, I was able to figure it out (see edit). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Opifex I suggest you answer the question instead of editing the question. Should be helpful to figure out for others in future.

Comment: Relevant: [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks @Atul and @KamilMaciorowski!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already shown in the edit, here's the answer:

executing *od -c -tx1 DATALOG.TXT | head -1*

gave me this:

```
0000000  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n  \r  \n
```

This hinted me that the file might have a bunch of newlines at the beginning, with the contents trailing. 
This turned out to be the case. That is why the file appeared empty in gedit and vim, but not with cat. Because I would only see the last lines of cat in terminal.